# Git; How to resynchronise repo after machine rebuild?

Tags: git

I had a hard disk failure but managed to get the disk back up to a state where I  could access the files on it.  Windows 10 died though (angryface, sadface). I rebuilt Windows using the same user name and hostname.

I copied over my surviving projects that were backed by repos on Github.  I copied over my RSA keys.  File and folder names and structures have been kept the same.

When I came to make a change to a project, it seems that Git now thinks that all files are different.

Why would Git see all the files as different, and is there something I can do to make Git auto-resynchronise?  It could be something like line-endings, perhaps I have inadvertently changed Git during the re-install, and selected different line endings from before.  It seems to be the only thing flagged in Git-gui.

How can I check if it is line endings, and how can I get Git to relax and accept the files as unchanged?

Comment: Do you have any local changes/branches that are not up on the remote? If not, just hard reset your branch, e.g. `git reset --hard origin/some/branch`

Comment: @CoryKramer Or if the Git folder has become corrupted, just delete and `git clone` the project again.  His hard disk seems to have a smell, and I'd probably avoid it.

Comment: I feel particularly dim, those are both good suggestions.  I have no pending changes so I can just clone the projects back to my new disk.  Hard disk is definitely toxic, replaced by SSD.  Thanks Tim, Cory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options to get back to a working state:

1. You can reset back to the contents of the most recent commit with `git reset --hard HEAD`.
2. You can just delete the folder and run `git clone <url to GitHub repo>`.

Note that both of these options are completely destructive. If there are any important local changes to your files, they will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Some extra files are generally not versioned, but can modify the behavior of git :

- the global `.gitconfig` file in your home directory
- on a per clone basis : the `.git/config` file inside each local clone of a repo

Generally, the end of line config option (`core.autocrlf`) is set in the global config file.

Were you able to retrieve your original `.gitconfig` file ?

Otherwise, you can re-set this option on your reinstalled system :

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Comment: I will take a look at this.  I will have a look for the .gitconfig file and check it out.  Very helpful response, thanks.